# How to message client when afterCreate database hook process is ready?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I have an express with sequelize (using postgres) REST backend server. When I post a create request from my client the database entry is created then a afterCreate hook is running a processing script for a second or so. This is running fine using the afterCreate hook form sequelize.

Subsequently I need to let the client know the processing is ready, upon which the client will run some process of its own. How do I message to the client?

Comment: Do you want to respond "twice"? I mean first after insert and then after processing is done? If yes you'd likely to switch from simple request-response model to some bidirectional communication channel (web sockets or server-sent events)

Comment: Yes, I need the second respond as it is the process timing is not fixed and the client process can only start when server process is finished. Indeed might mean that I need web sockets or SSE, but as I have not experience with these I do not know and it might be 'overkill' as other communication of my app fits standard REST and CRUD just fine.

Comment: Hmm, but it your client can't do anything before server side processing is done you could respond once you have finished all the stuff server side. AFAIK you could simply return a Promise from `afterCreate` hook.

Comment: Haha! Yeah, I think it probably is as easy as that..., I see if I can get my thingy working and then come back on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Node expert and my answer might be wrong, but based on the https://groundberry.github.io/development/2016/11/06/continue-building-your-node-app-with-express-and-sequelize.html couldn't you do the following:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
//node return reply after running the create
  return models.User.create({ username: req.body.username }).then(function() {      
    return res.json({ message: 'New user created' });
  });
});
```